# When is xarrays `xr.apply_ufunc(...dask='parallelized')` fast?

Tags: python, numpy, dask, python-xarray, large-data

I open data from the ERA5 Google Cloud Zarr archive. I do some refactoring (change time resolution, select Northern Hemisphere only, etc.), where the operations are applied on dask data.

This is how the xarray DataArray looks like:

[image]

Then I apply a numpy function that works on multi-dimensional data using `xr.apply_ufunc`:

[image]

I tested two scenarios, one where the data is loaded first and ufunc is applied on `numpy` and one where ufunc is applied on `dask` data and the result computed afterwards.

### option 1: compute data first)

[image]

**This is fast.**

### option 2: compute result later)

[image]

**This is slow.**

### Question: Why is option 1 so much faster?

I'd think that `dask=parallelized` distributes the work to be done across multiple cores. Is numpy doing that as well? Why is applying ufunc to numpy still so much faster?

As soon as the dataset becomes large, it will be unfeasible to load the data into memory first (option 1). Therefore, I want to make sure that I'm not doing something stupid makes `dask=parallelized` very slow.

Thanks.

Comment: Please put the code into code blocks instead of posting it using screenshots, doing that the question can be searched better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the array is small enough to comfortably fit into memory the overhead of spinning up dask workers, scheduling those workers and just the general I/O of splitting data, computing it and stitching it back together makes dask a lot slower.

Dask helps scaling up. It isn't good for speeding up array computations that fit completely into your memory.

If what you are doing is stupid really depends on what the function `_to_lon_lat` is doing. But in general, if what you are doing in that function can be done with native xarray functions, then you shouldn't use `apply_ufunc` but instead those xarray functions since all of them work with dask out of the box.

Comment: Thanks. So does that mean that dask only provides potential speedup compared to a solution which would manually loops over chunks? So `xr.apply_ufunc(xr_dask_object, parallelized=True)` is slower than `xr.apply_ufunc(xr_numpy_object)` but faster than `for one_chunk in xr_dask_object: `xr.apply_ufunc(one_chunk.load()).chunk()` ? In my case I apply `scipy.signal.griddata` inside `_to_lon_lat` and this works only on numpy, not on xarray objects.

Comment: Yes that's basically it. Dask offers you to efficiently work with data that doesn't fit into memory. So yes, compared to a manual looping over chunks it is faster (and much easier). But it is unlikely to speed up any computations that fit completely into memory.